# Get the link redirected from webview android

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to implement a payment gateway in android, and the payment processor requires sending some parameters when the "Pay" button is clicked. The sample link is:

https://vpay.com/?p=linkToken&v_merchant_id=qa331322179752&merchant_ref=234-567-890&memo=Bulk+order+from+McAckney+Web+Shop&total=13000&
notify_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fnotification.php&
success_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fthank_you.html&fail_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Ffailed.html

Now if the parameters are inputted correctly, the link returns another link in the format: https://vpay.com/pay/bnlink/xxxxxxxx-x0 which when visited brings up VPay payment page that can be used for payment based on the parameters supplied.

The payment processor should have employed an automatic redirection when the new link is generated, instead, it just displays the new link and stays there.  Is there a way to get this new "RETURNED" link and then visit it so users can input the payment info.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Following method of Webview will work if you are using your own webview in activity or fragment for the payment stuff. below is the piece of code which will help:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
                view.loadUrl(url);
                Log.v(TAG,"html content of url:"+ getHtml(String url) ); 

                return true; 
            } 

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " +url);

            } 

        });
```

in shouldOverrideUrlLoading method you will add your condition according to the url whether to load this url in webview or not.

And to get html content of the url use below Method:

```
public String getHtml(String url) {
    HttpClient vClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet vGet = new HttpGet(url);
    String response = "";    

    try { 
        ResponseHandler<String> vHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        response = vClient.execute(vGet, vHandler);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the new returned link is not in the "address bar" it is displayed on the body of the page. Will the above code work?